# How to remove duplicates from json response and sum their value

Tags: jquery

I want to display a dynamic table, data for which i am getting from an api response. But there are some duplicate entries in json response, i want to remove the duplicates and add the values of corresponding duplicates and form a new json with no duplicate records and their added values.

Moreover after doing this, i have to loop through the new json formed, and display the records in descending order of "count" in the table. Also, the number of records that should be displayed will depend on the value that user will select from input type "number".

Currently in my below code, i am able to loop through the json response and display the number of records in table that user will select.

But I am not getting how to find duplicate records, sum their value and again form a new JSON.(The part which i am able to implement is the second part..)

```
var responseData = [{
    "issueId": "otfa_R5-9_39",
    "IssueDescription": "2 duplicated blocks of code must be removed.",
    "drmArtifactQualifier": "Corrected",
    "drmArtifactType": "Algorithm/Method",
    "criteria": "Methodology",
    "timing": "Tactical",
    "count": "100",
    "recommendation": "Ensure formulas are validated / proven",
    "drmTarget": "Code"
}, {
    "issueId": "otfa_R5-9_8",
    "IssueDescription": "This block of commented-out lines of code should be removed.",
    "drmArtifactQualifier": "Added",
    "drmArtifactType": "Assignment/Initialization",
    "criteria": "Technology",
    "timing": "Tactical",
    "count": "100",
    "recommendation": "Build automated QA into your code",
    "drmTarget": "Code"
}, {
    "issueId": "otfa_R5-9_24",
    "IssueDescription": "This block of commented-out lines of code should be removed.",
    "drmArtifactQualifier": "Added",
    "drmArtifactType": "Assignment/Initialization",
    "criteria": "Technology",
    "timing": "Tactical",
    "count": "100",
    "recommendation": "Build automated QA into your code",
    "drmTarget": "Code"
}, {
    "issueId": "otfa_R5-9_31",
    "IssueDescription": "This block of commented-out lines of code should be removed.",
    "drmArtifactQualifier": "Added",
    "drmArtifactType": "Assignment/Initialization",
    "criteria": "Technology",
    "timing": "Tactical",
    "count": "100",
    "recommendation": "Build automated QA into your code",
    "drmTarget": "Code"
}, {
    "issueId": "otfa_R5-9_10",
    "IssueDescription": "Remove this unused method parameter \"group\".",
    "drmArtifactQualifier": "Removed",
    "drmArtifactType": "Assignment/Initialization",
    "criteria": "Methodology",
    "timing": "Quick Win",
    "count": "100",
    "recommendation": "Review code by programmer peers",
    "drmTarget": "Code"
}, {
    "issueId": "otfa_R5-9_86",
    "IssueDescription": "Define and throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one.",
    "drmArtifactQualifier": "Added",
    "drmArtifactType": "Assignment/Initialization",
    "criteria": "Methodology",
    "timing": "Quick Win",
    "count": "100",
    "recommendation": "Review code by programmer peers",
    "drmTarget": "Code"
}];

var table = $('#reportTableBody');
var rowNum = parseInt($("#table-row-num").val() || 5, 10);
table = table.html("");
var filterData = responseData.slice(0, rowNum);
$.each(filterData, function(key, value) {
    table.append('<tr id=reportTableData><td>' + value.IssueDescription + '</td>' + '<td>' + value.drmArtifactType + '</td>' + '<td>' + value.count + '</td>' + '<td>' + value.recommendation + '</td></tr>');
});
```

I have attached sample response in responseData variable for reference. And the duplicate values that i need to filter is in "IssueDescription" key and i need to add "count" in case of duplicate issueDescription. Anyone please help me to form a new json.

Comment: I see only two element duplicated: **"This block of commented-out lines of code should be removed."**. How do you sum these two elements? Can you clarify? Thanks

Comment: what is the value of **reportTableData**?

Comment: yes i have attached small part of response only to avoid confusion. See, the text "This block of commented-out lines of code should be removed" is in issueDescription key. And this is repeating 3 times, so i want to add its "count", which is 100,100,100...so i need this text 1 time with "count" value as "300".

Comment: reportTableData is just the <tr> id..It doesn't affect anyway. Problem is to form a new JSON from existing one with no duplicate entries for IssueDescription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to remove duplicates and sum count on duplicated values you can use [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var responseData = [{
    "issueId": "otfa_R5-9_39",
    "IssueDescription": "2 duplicated blocks of code must be removed.",
    "drmArtifactQualifier": "Corrected",
    "drmArtifactType": "Algorithm/Method",
    "criteria": "Methodology",
    "timing": "Tactical",
    "count": "100",
    "recommendation": "Ensure formulas are validated / proven",
    "drmTarget": "Code"
}, {
    "issueId": "otfa_R5-9_8",
    "IssueDescription": "This block of commented-out lines of code should be removed.",
    "drmArtifactQualifier": "Added",
    "drmArtifactType": "Assignment/Initialization",
    "criteria": "Technology",
    "timing": "Tactical",
    "count": "100",
    "recommendation": "Build automated QA into your code",
    "drmTarget": "Code"
}, {
    "issueId": "otfa_R5-9_24",
    "IssueDescription": "This block of commented-out lines of code should be removed.",
    "drmArtifactQualifier": "Added",
    "drmArtifactType": "Assignment/Initialization",
    "criteria": "Technology",
    "timing": "Tactical",
    "count": "100",
    "recommendation": "Build automated QA into your code",
    "drmTarget": "Code"
}, {
    "issueId": "otfa_R5-9_31",
    "IssueDescription": "This block of commented-out lines of code should be removed.",
    "drmArtifactQualifier": "Added",
    "drmArtifactType": "Assignment/Initialization",
    "criteria": "Technology",
    "timing": "Tactical",
    "count": "100",
    "recommendation": "Build automated QA into your code",
    "drmTarget": "Code"
}, {
    "issueId": "otfa_R5-9_10",
    "IssueDescription": "Remove this unused method parameter \"group\".",
    "drmArtifactQualifier": "Removed",
    "drmArtifactType": "Assignment/Initialization",
    "criteria": "Methodology",
    "timing": "Quick Win",
    "count": "100",
    "recommendation": "Review code by programmer peers",
    "drmTarget": "Code"
}, {
    "issueId": "otfa_R5-9_86",
    "IssueDescription": "Define and throw a dedicated exception instead of using a generic one.",
    "drmArtifactQualifier": "Added",
    "drmArtifactType": "Assignment/Initialization",
    "criteria": "Methodology",
    "timing": "Quick Win",
    "count": "100",
    "recommendation": "Review code by programmer peers",
    "drmTarget": "Code"
}];

responseData = responseData.reduce(function(a, e, idx, arr) {
    if (a.length == 0) {
        a.push(e);
    } else {
        var idx = a.findIndex(function(ele) {
            return ele.IssueDescription == e.IssueDescription;
        });
        if (idx == -1) {
            e.count = +e.count; // convert to number...
            a.push(e);
        } else {
            a[idx].count += +e.count;
        }
    }
    return a;
}, []).sort((a, b) => b.count -  a.count);

console.log(responseData);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help..It is serving my purpose. Can u please guide me where i should apply sorting ?

Comment: @AnjaliChaudhary [.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) added to snippet. Let me know. Thanks